# Where is the .rspec configuration file located exactly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Working through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and stuck here "To run RSpec and Spork with Autotest, we need to configure RSpec to use the --drb option by default, which we can arrange by adding it to the .rspec configuration file in the Rails root directory (Listing 3.14)."

When I search my file structure I can not find a single file with .rspec file extension? How do I access this file to update the configuration?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a mac you will not see these files just like you will not see the gitignore file

what you need to do in order to access this file is from the root directory of the app just click (command line)

```
mate .rspec
```

this will open the file if it's there, and if not, it will create it.

Comment: This helped me solve my issue. A tutorial was asking me to edit this file and add --drb to it but I was adding it to a the rspec.helper file because I couldn't see a config file. Stumbled upon this post which helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you add `gem 'rspec-rails'` to your Gemfile, you can use the `rails g rspec:install` command.
This will create the .rspec file in the root of the Rails application. It will also create a spec folder and a file inside it 'spec_helper.rb'

If you do not want to write this command, you may simply create the file manually. If you are using a linux machine, the hidden files can be seen with a `<ctrl-h>` command. You may also try the `ls -a` in any unix terminal to see all hidden and non hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

Files on mac that begin with `.` are not shown by default.  In Terminal, if you type `ls -a` you'll see all of the "dotfiles" that are in the folder.

If this file doesn't exist yet (it probably doesn't) then you just need to create it using your favorite editor.